# Seeeduino Motor Shield Power Supply

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I'm looking to drive two DC motors (on a toy RC car) using a Seeeduino and Seeed Motor Shield V2, but can't manage to get the power scheme right. Right now, a 9V battery connected to the shield powers everything (i.e. LEDs are illuminated on the shield and seeeduino), but when I try running the motors everything flickers and the motors don't move (I assume this is because there isn't enough current). I've managed to get them working when plugging a USB and 9V battery (at the same time) into the seeeduino, as well as when plugging a 9V into the seeeduino and another into the shield (at the same time). Both of these configurations leave me feeling uneasy, as I'm not sure how the power sources will interact.

Further, there is a jumper (MB_EN) on the shield which, according to my research, should isolate the shield from the seeeduino when removed. The documentation (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Motor_Shield_V2.0) alludes to the fact that this jumper doesn't work, however. Indeed, when I try removing it, power is lost altogether.

I've found conflicting answers to this problem, none of which seems definitive. I've also found tutorials where people did exactly the same thing (with a proper arduino, mind you...) by plugging a single 9V battery to the shield. This should be possible.

I've exhausted just about every resource I can think of, and have spent innumerable hours searching up a solution -- nothing yet. Any help would be great.